# What does this picture in the video to the Radiohead song Just represent?

Tags: music-video, artwork

In the video for the Radiohead song *Just*, there's a picture on the wall at [2:35](https://youtu.be/oIFLtNYI3Ls?t=155s) containing this image:

[image: picture]

My first reaction is that it represents something connected with the Christian church because of the two crosses decorating what appears to be an altar, in the foreground, but I'm not sure exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they have anything to do with Christianity (apart from the fact they likely originate from a time and place when Christianity was the norm, and the artist was probably Christian). It looks like an engraving from a treatise on architecture. In the middle there is a parallel projection of what appears to be a city gate or a set of double towers. Below it, the crosses you refer to, is probably a floor plan of the larger structure the gate is a part of. This combination of projections was quite common in architectural treatises from the 16th to the 18th century, see the following, for example:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.sellingantiques.co.uk/767720/rare-drawing-17th-century-italian-architectural-rotunda-van-der-lay#gallery-1). click for larger image.</sup>

As for the meaning, it's hard to tell. The room Radiohead is playing in actually has three of these prints, on all three walls except the windowed one. They could simply be innocuous decorations, quite timeless, and blending in well with the set. They emphasize the theatrical quality of the set and the video, and might have been chosen because they represent blueprints, the (ideal(ized)) concept of a potential reality, and the song is about an obscure truth underlying humankind.